# 1 Hosted App Domain for 2 seperate Farms

Tags: administration, provider-hosted-app

I am working with SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on-premise and am new to provider hosted (self-hosted) Apps.
I have multiple single server developer instances: myDev01, myDev02, myDev03, myDev05, etc.
I have a single Hosted App server on the same domain as my dev instances that only myDev05 has been using running devapps.domain.com

I have the need to integrate this hosted app onto another development server myDev02

I am wondering if I need to setup a second hosted app server so that I can have sevapps02.rightviewweb.com or if I can set that web applicatoin up on the same hosted app server but just as a different web application.

I've ben able to deploy the .app file and add the web parts that the hosted app fills, but they show nothing so I'm thinking something is off regarding the hosted app server.

I need this setup as quickly as possible for a demo so that would be the priority.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. You need to use the same client id, secret issuerid, clientsigningcertificatepath and certificate. Basically, the information in the appSettings tag of the hosted app's web.config is referred to when setting up your trust on the other sharepoint farm. I'm doing this for a couple of development farms. Ideally each farm would have their own hosted app server but its not always possible, as in our case where the hosted app has a good bit of infrastructure behind it and duplicating that requires a good bit of effort and expense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same *target* server where the provider hosted addin code runs (i.e. an IIS box), but the app domain and configuration within the farm is unique on a per-farm basis.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm a bit slow on the uptake. What that tells me is that hostedapp.domain.com URL can be used in myDev01 and in Mydev02, 2 seperate farms,  but if I wanted to add a second hosted app to MyDev02 it would need to be hostedapp02.domain.com

Comment: One thing to consider is each farm will have a unique client id/secret for your app (because they're generated by the farm rather than specified) so you may need to still have a different FQDN/path for the provider hosted app.

Comment: I reused the ones from the other development server on this farm instead of autogenerating them. These were entered into the appregnew.aspx page.  I wanted to avoid the need to setup another web.config transform for the developer since he is brand new and overwhelmed as it is.